# L2 cache lines miss count

Tags: c, linux, performance-testing, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I want to calculate total no of L2 cache miss while I am running one particular program A. Is there any way to find cache miss in L2 cache ?

I got to know,  Core i7 CPU's performance counter event types "L2_LINES_OUT " is available to Counts L2 cache lines evicted, but don't know how to use it ?

I am using linux and Intel i7 IvyBridge machine.

Any pointer or link will be highly appreciated .

Comment: Why does that matter to you? Can't you simply benchmark your program?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I think this is exactly what he's trying to do :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this summary](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/docs/intel-ivybridge-events.php), you can use the `l2_rqsts` subevents:

```
0x01: (name=demand_data_rd_hit) Demand Data Read requests that hit L2 cache
0x03: (name=all_demand_data_rd) Demand Data Read requests
0x04: (name=rfo_hit) RFO requests that hit L2 cache
0x08: (name=rfo_miss) RFO requests that miss L2 cache
0x0c: (name=all_rfo) RFO requests to L2 cache
0x10: (name=code_rd_hit) L2 cache hits when fetching instructions, code reads.
0x20: (name=code_rd_miss) L2 cache misses when fetching instructions
0x30: (name=all_code_rd) L2 code requests
0x40: (name=pf_hit) Requests from the L2 hardware prefetchers that hit L2 cache
0x80: (name=pf_miss) Requests from the L2 hardware prefetchers that miss L2 cache
0xc0: (name=all_pf) Requests from L2 hardware prefetchers
```

You can just use - `(all_demand_data_rd - demand_data_rd_hit)` to count the demand misses

Answer (score 1):

The IBM documentation [here](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/clresctr/vxrx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cluster.pedev.v1r3.pedev100.doc/bl7ug_derivedmetricsivybridge.htm) might be helpful.

It describes various expressions for many different metrics on Ivybridge. The one you want appears to be

```
 *Instruction fetch from L2 cache miss rate*
 100.0 * X_L2_RQSTS_IFETCH_MISS / X_L2_RQSTS_IFETCHES
```

Comment: `IFETCH` events would only count instruction cache misses (the ones the miss the code L1 and lookup the shared L2)

Answer (score 0):

Search PAPI, it is a tool that you can use to read the PMU before and after the code segment you want to collect the L2 cache misses.